# How to strip text from XML string in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML string where some nodes have text between the tags, like so:

```
<note>
<to>Text between tags</to>
<from>More text</from>
<empty />
</note>
```

In Scala, how can I remove the text between these tags so that I get a string like this?:

```
<note><to></to><from></from><empty /></note>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`RewriteRule`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-xml/#scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule) for this and set Text nodes to Empty e.g.

```
val removeText = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): NodeSeq = n match  {
    case e: Text => NodeSeq.Empty
    case _ => n
  }
}
```

Then you can use [`RuleTransformer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-xml/#scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer) to transform your XML e.g.

```
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("myData.xml")
  val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()
  val xml = XML.loadString(lines)
  val output = new RuleTransformer(removeText).transform(xml)
  println(output)
```

Output:
`<note><to/><from/><empty/></note>`